# Java: NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, interface, nosuchmethoderror

For my program the goal is to use a bunch of interfaces and create a program that makes a test and allows the user to take it.  The specific issue I have is with the interface IQuestionFactory, which assists in making questions in the TestMaker class.  I'm using a class loader given by my professor, which uses the name of the class I need to load as a parameter.  I cannot figure out why I'm getting the error.

### Error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.api.IQuestionFactory.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at test.util.MyClassLoader.createInstance(MyClassLoader.java:37)
    at test.maker.TestMaker.main(TestMaker.java:13)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.maker.TestMaker.main(TestMaker.java:14)
```

### ClassLoader

```
package test.util;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class MyClassLoader {

    //instead of using the constructor, we provide a single instance of MyClassLoader
    public static MyClassLoader instance = new MyClassLoader();

    //by making the constructor private, we ensure that it can't be called.
    private MyClassLoader() {

    }

    /**
     * Load class of the given className and create an object of that class.
     * @param className the name of the class including its package. e.g.  test.impl.QuestionFactory
     * @return return the object created.
     */
    public Object createInstance(String className) {
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            Class loadedMyClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);
            Constructor constructor = loadedMyClass.getConstructor();
            Object myClassObject = constructor.newInstance();
            return myClassObject;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### TestMaker Class

```
package test.maker;

import test.api.IQuestion;
import test.api.IQuestionFactory;
import test.api.ITestSet;
import test.util.MyClassLoader;

public class TestMaker {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        MyClassLoader cl = MyClassLoader.instance;

        IQuestionFactory factory = (IQuestionFactory) cl.createInstance("test.api.IQuestionFactory");
        ITestSet testset = factory.makeEmptyTestSet();

        String question = "Which of the following people was not a US president?";
        String[] choices = {"George Washington", "Benjamin Franklin", "Andrew Jackson", "Mr. Rodgers"};
        int answer = 1;

        IQuestion q = factory.makeMultipleChoice(question, choices, answer);
        testset.add(q);

        factory.save(testset,"Questions");

    }
}
```

### IQuestionFactory Interface

```
package test.api;

import java.io.IOException;


public interface IQuestionFactory {
    /**
     * @param question The question
     * @param choices The choices as an array
     * @param answer The index to the answer in the choices array
     * @return An instance of a multiple choice question.
     */
    public IQuestion makeMultipleChoice(String question, String[] choices, int answer);


    /**
     * @param question The question.
     * @param answer The answer
     * @return an instance of a true-false question
     */
    public IQuestion makeTrueFalse(String question, boolean answer);

    /** 
     * @param question The question, including the blanks
     * @param answers Array of answers to the blanks
     * @return an instance of a fill-in-the-blank question
     */
    public IQuestion makeFillInBlank(String question, String [] answers);

    /**
     * @param question The question.
     * @param keywords The answers as a list of key words.  
     * @return an instance of a short answer question.
     */
    public IQuestion makeShortAnswer(String question, String[] keywords);

    /**
     * @param filename The file containing the test set.
     * @return A Test set
     * @throws IOException if can't load the file.
     */
    public ITestSet load(String filename);


    /**
     * @param testSet The test set to be stored.
     * @param filename  The filename to be used.
     * @return true if save is successful
     * @throws IOException if unable to save the test set.
     */
    public boolean save(ITestSet testSet, String filename);


    /**
     * Create an empty test set.
     * 
     * @return an empty test set.
     */
    public ITestSet makeEmptyTestSet();


}
```

Comment: Pls format your code.  What is the output of your stacktrace?  Where is the error?

Comment: Are you trying to create an instance of an interface?

Comment: When asking for help resolving an exception, you're more likely to get useful help if you post the full exception message and stack trace, not just the name of the exception type.

Comment: Your `MyClassLoader` class creates a `ClassLoader` and `Class` object. If these classes exist, it may help to include that code as well. As the exception error implies, you are trying to invoke a method that does not exist, so one of the objects is calling a method that isn't there.

Comment: My bad, sorry.  I edited the post.

Comment: Based on the added error message, it appears there is no `getConstructor()` method in the `Class` class. So `Constructor constructor = loadedMyClass.getConstructor();` throws the error.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to create an instance of an interface, which doesn't make any sense. You can only create an instance of a class. You need to implement the interface with another class and use that class as the parameter for `cl.createInstance`.

**Edit:** Although I honestly have no idea why you're using reflection here at all. You should probably be doing something like this:

```
IQuestionFactory factory = new MyQuestionFactory()
```

Where MyQuestionFactory implements IQuestionFactory. It's more efficient like that and then the compiler would catch your mistakes. What you are doing right now is:

```
IQuestionFactory factory = new IQuestionFactory()
```

And the compiler would catch that.